# How to list backups when not connected to target DB in Oracle RMAN

Tags: oracle, backup, recovery, rman

I'm trying to list backups in RMAN completed within a certain date range. This works fine when I can connect to the target database and recovery catalog.

However, I'm assuming a situation where I am not able to connect to target database, but only have access to the recovery catalog. When I input a query with date specified, it fails, saying it isn't connected to target db.

```
rman catalog rco/Password;
SET DBID 12345678;

RMAN> LIST BACKUP COMPLETED BETWEEN '01-DEC-21' AND '10-DEC-21';

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of list command at 12/14/2021 11:54:04
RMAN-06171: not connected to target database
```

Answer (score 0):

The recovery catalog is nothing more than an application schema, with the application being rman.  Connect to it with sqlplus (or any other general purpose client of your choosing, like SQL Dev) as the catalog owner, then query the relevant RC_* tables.  They are documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rcmrf/recovery-catalog-views.html#GUID-EDE04F79-9565-49D3-9934-1536016E6EE4), in the [Database Backup and Recovery Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/rcmrf/index.html).